# ASP.NET MVC 5 ModelState.IsValid is always returning false in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing a ModelState.IsValid false everytime. I debugged the whole action. And when I expand the ModelState error section, I find System.Web.Mvc.Model error. In my model the Status attribute is declared as Required through Data Annotation. So basically the error is showing that my status is required in the model. That is why it gives the validation error.

This is my model

```
public class CompanyResource
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Date of Joining")]
    public DateTime? DOJ { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectSiteResource> ProjectSiteResources { get; set; }
 }
```

}

This is my Action

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Position,DOJ,Phone,Address,Status")] CompanyResource companyResource)
    {
       var isAjaxRequest = Request.IsAjaxRequest();
        ModelState["Status"].Errors.Clear();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CompanyResource.Add(companyResource);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (isAjaxRequest)
            {
                var staff = new SelectList(db.CompanyResource.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
                return Json(new { Flag = true, CompanyResources = staff }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            Success(string.Format("Successfully save data !"), true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (!isAjaxRequest) return View(companyResource);
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my another method in the same controller

```
  public JsonResult GetStaff()
    {
        try
        {
            var staff = new SelectList(db.CompanyResource.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            return Json(new { Flag = true, CompanyResources = staff }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Flag = false, Msg = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

This is my View

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @required = "required" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="Status">
                                        <option value="A">Active</option>
                                        <option value="I">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: did you check all the data annotations...all of them need to have a DisplayName in model..

Comment: I checked it. The attribute is set to [required].

Comment: Are you not populating Status value from UI?

Comment: yes I do. Like this one.<select class="form-control" id="Status">
                                            <option value="A">Active</option>
                                            <option value="I">Inactive</option>
                                        </select>

Comment: This is my model.   [StringLength(1)]
        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

Comment: why not use @html.DropDownListFor

Comment: any example? I gave the id as named as Status. And this Status is going to the action where it occurs the error that the field is required in the model.

Comment: Is it failing to get the id as I written in the views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comment to your question you indicated this is your HTML and model:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Status"> 
    <option value="A">Active</option> 
    <option value="I">Inactive</option> 
</select>
[StringLength(1)] [Required] public string Status { get; set; }
```

You need to set the `name` attribute of the select tag for MVC binding to work. So add the name like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Status" name="Status"> 
    <option value="A">Active</option> 
    <option value="I">Inactive</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Sure I will! I have another question. When I submit the form the latest data is not loaded on the dropdown. The dropdown shows empty. But when I refreshed the entire page the dropdown loads the value and I can see the last thing I added. I did that with ajax request. Debugged the entire solution but not getting an error.

Comment: You can ask another question and either I or someone else will help you. It is not good to start another question in the comments because it may require a lot of back and forth. Also, without seeing your controller code and your ajax code, I or anyone else will not be able to help you. So make sure you include that code in your question.

Comment: Please review the following link. I have set a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47108605/8884133