# Dropdown is not loading data while I create new employee but when the page is refreshed it loads the new data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I add new employee the inserted employee does not show up in the drop down list but when I refresh the entire page the dropdowns shows the data I inserted. The problem is why the drop down list becomes empty after adding new employee. The code is running smoothly but I am not getting the reason behind this.
This is the UI. Here I can create new Employees and then can add employees to the grid 
[image]

This is the Modal View here the fields are needed to create a new staff

[image]

[Here you can see that the drop down is empty. But when I refresh the entire page I can see the whole list in the drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDjEv.png)

[But when the entire page is refreshed the inserted data shows nicely with the other employees coming from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD7h3.png)

Now let us see the code part here,
This is my model

```
 public class CompanyResource
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Date of Joining")]
    public DateTime? DOJ { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectSiteResource> ProjectSiteResources { get; set; }

}
```

This is my Controller and actions

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Position,DOJ,Phone,Address,Status")] CompanyResource companyResource)
    {

        var isAjaxRequest = Request.IsAjaxRequest();

        ModelState["Status"].Errors.Clear();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CompanyResource.Add(companyResource);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (isAjaxRequest)
            {
                var staff = new SelectList(db.CompanyResource.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
                return Json(new { Flag = true, CompanyResources = staff }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            Success(string.Format("Successfully save data !"), true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (!isAjaxRequest) return View(companyResource);
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


 public JsonResult GetStaff()
    {
        try
        {
            var staff = new SelectList(db.CompanyResource.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            return Json(new { Flag = true, CompanyResources = staff }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Flag = false, Msg = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

This is my View. The scripts are written here

```
var optionsStaff = new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    //Confirm = "Do you want to add a new person?",
    //OnBegin = "OnBegin",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccessStaff",
    OnComplete = "OnCompleteStaff",
    OnFailure = "OnFai lureStaff"
};
```

This is my Modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="resourceStaffModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staffModalTitle">Add Staff</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "CompanyResources", null, optionsStaff, new { @id = "staffCreateForm" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class = "form-control" })

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Position", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBox("Position", null, new {@class = "form-control"})

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("ToDate", "Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.TextBox("DOJ", null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Phone", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBox("Phone", null, new {@class = "form-control"})

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Address", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBox("Address", null, new {@class = "form-control"})

                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @required = "required" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="Status" name="Status">
                                        <option value="A">Active</option>
                                        <option value="I">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>                                                 

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script that I am receiving a Json response from the actions

```
    function OnBeginStaff() {}

    function OnCompleteStaff() {}

    function OnSuccessStaff() {
        $('#Name').val("");
        $('#Position').val("");
        $('#DOJ').val("");
        $('#Phone').val("");
        $('#Address').val("");
        $('#Status').val("");           

        $('#resourceStaffModal').modal('hide');
        $.get("@Url.Action("GetStaff", "CompanyResources")", function(resp) {
            if (resp.Flag) {
                $("#RName").empty().html("<option value>--Select--</option>");
                $.each(resp.GetStaff, function (key, item) {
                    $("<option>").attr("value", item.Value).html(item.Text).appendTo("#RName");
                });
            }
        });

    }

    function OnFailureStaff() {}
```

Comment: I couldn't find the error message in your post. Did you include it ? If so, can you make it more visible ?

Comment: No error occurs actually. Data is saved successfully. But when I create a new employee the drop down list shows empty but when I refresh the entire page it loads the data I just created.

Comment: Please update your post to explain this. Your question starts with "I am getting an error when I add something" so it's quite confusing

Comment: Okay. Updating. I have given the image. Please check what is going on!

Comment: `.appendTo($("#RName"))`, not `.appendTo("#RName")`

Comment: But there is a whole lot of other code that makes no sense including why you return a `JsonResult` in your `Create()` method (which you never use anyway)

Comment: Because there are two types of requests here. Ajax request is one of them. And the other one is normal Post request. When the request is ajax type it goes to the if condtion and check if it is true or not. If it returns true then it sends Json true flag to the view and execute according to it. @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Did you not understand my comment - returning a `JsonResult` from your `@Ajax.BeginForm()` makes no sense - and you never even use it anyway - its just pointless extra overhead since you then make another ajax call to return exactly the dame data

Comment: Get rid of the obsolete `@Ajax.BeginForm()` and just use `$.ajax()` to post you form and return the option values and update the DOM. Although even that is unnecessary since all you need to return is the ID of the new `CompanyResource` since you already have its `Name` in the modal form (and then just append the one `<option>` element

Comment: Now I have understood what you meant to say! Thank you @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your controller is returning:

```
return Json(new { Flag = true, CompanyResources = staff }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Please note the 2nd property `CompanyResources`. Now here is what you are doing with the data returned:

```
$.each(resp.GetStaff, function (key, item) {
                $("<option>").attr("value", item.Value).html(item.Text).appendTo("#RName");
            });
```

See you are iterating the `GetStaff` property of the response but that is not correct. You should be iterating the `CompanyResources` property. So change to this:

```
 $.each(resp.CompanyResources, function (key, item) {
                $("<option>").attr("value", item.Value).html(item.Text).appendTo($("#RName"));
            });
```

Also as Stephen mentioned, it should be `.appendTo($("#RName"))`, not `.appendTo("#RName")` which i have changed above.

Comment: @tazbirulhaque sorry I don't understand what you mean by your comment.